# Problems with the elements creating of the array of structure type

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

I've created a **Structure** type named `Location` as

```
struct Location {
    var XCoor: Int
    var YCoor: Int
}
```

I want to create a array of type `Location` I named it as `places`

```
var places : Array<Location>
```

Quesiont: How to create the element for the Array?

Two of my wrong guesses

```
places[0](Xcoor: 10, YCoor: 12)// error: cannot call value of non-function type 'Location'


places[0].XCoor = 10
places[0].YCoor = 12 //error: constant 'places' passed by reference before being initialized
```

Comment: If you need clarification on the syntax for working with Arrays, I would definately reccommend [Apple's really clear and concise guide on it](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID107) (and the rest of Swift fundamentals).

Comment: @originaluser2 thanks for the document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you may want to use constants (instead of variables) and lowercase names inside `Location`.

```
struct Location {
    let x: Int
    let y: Int
}
```

Next this is how you create a mutable array of `Locations`(s)

```
var places = [Location]()
```

And this is how you add a location to places

```
places.append(Location(x: 1, y: 3))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let firstLocation = Location(XCoor: 10, Ycoor: 10) 

places.append(firstLocation)
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is as follows:

```
struct Location {
    var XCoor: Int
    var YCoor: Int
}

var places : [Location] // a bit of syntactic sugar, dropping the Array<...>
places = [] // actually create the empty array

var places2 = [Location]() // alternate, shorter, more swifty version of the two lines before

places.append(Location(XCoor: 10, YCoor: 12)) // create an instance of the struct append it to the array
```

Comment: @luk2320 thanks a lot for your detialed explanation and code demo